# How to trigger function on end of Carousel Slider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel, dart-pub

I have used the [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package for displaying posts to my users in my application.
I want to load more posts whenever the user reaches the last post in the carousel.
Where can I trigger the function that will add more data to the list of items, which in case is

> homeData

This is how my code looks:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: getMoreData, //fetches new post on refresh
    child: CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        height: 650,
        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      ),
      items: homeData, //list of widgets that are displayed in the carousel
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey Buro, How to manage next and previous button with this widget ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can give a callback to `onPageChanged`, which will be called whenever the post is swiped.**

Here's how you can do it :

```
List itemList = [1,2,3,4,5];


CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions( 
        height: 400.0,
        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
          if(index == itemList.length - 1) {
            //do whatever you want to do on your last page change
          }
        },
      ),
      items: itemList.map((i) {
        return Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.amber
              ),
              child: Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
            );
          },
        );
      }).toList(),
    )
```

Comment: Hey Buro, How to manage next and previous button with this widget ?

Comment: I implemented no widgets, it was a tiktok like slider, you check more [here](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)